# Conditionally setting a javascript function after posting of a form

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

Apologies for the *very* basic question - crash course in javascript coming up! But before that, I have a javascript function:

```
 function toggle(request)
```

The function simply toggles a div as visible/invisible. I can trigger the behaviour I want from this function using an *onclick* event as follows:

```
<input type="radio" name="complete" value="true" id="complete_yes" 
onclick="toggle('true');"/>
```

This works fine, but after posting a form, under certain conditions I want the radio button to be automatically selected and the javascript function to be automatically set to:

```
toggle('true')
```

... thus revealing the div contents. I've got the "checked" part working, but how do I get the javascript function to conditionally be set to true aswell?

```
<input type="radio" name="complete" value="true" {if $data.complete == true}checked{/if} id="complete_yes" 
onclick="toggle('true');"/>
```

Comment: Reading this back, I think the only 'div' being revealed here is me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decided to learn jQuery instead! The syntax below achieves the desired result and is very maintainable!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#complete_yes').toggle(function () {
    $('#repair_complete').removeClass('hidden');
 }, function() {
    $('#repair_complete').addClass('hidden');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What about testing, in your JS `toggle` function, if the div has to be made visible or not depending on the "checked" status of your input ?

Something a bit like this, I guess :

```
function toggle()
{
    if (document.getElementById('YOUR_INPUT_ID').checked) {
        document.getElementById('YOUR_DIV_ID').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('YOUR_DIV_ID').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Absolutly not tested, but I think you'll get the idea :-)

*(I never know if the input in considered as "checked" before or after the JS function on onclick is called... So you might actually have to invert the '`block`' and '`none`' settings)*

And, if you have several inputs/divs, you can pass their ids as parameters to the `toggle` function...

That way, you'd never have to worry about any kind of "initialization" for that function.

Note that you could also test if the div is visible, with something like this :

```
function toggle()
{
    if (document.getElementById('YOUR_DIV_ID').style.display == 'none') {
        document.getElementById('YOUR_DIV_ID').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('YOUR_DIV_ID').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

*(not tested either)*

That way, your function would really **toggle** the div's displaying, each time it is called.

Comment: Thanks - sounds promising, will test tomorrow!

Comment: If you are finding that the .checked property may not be altered until after the click event fires - try wrapping the whole if statement in a setTimeout(funciton(){ if....else... }, 100); - So it checks a little after you click for the checked property?

Comment: I'm not having a huge amount of success with this unfortunately - what should the id be in your first example 'YOUR_INPUT_ID' - is this "complete_yes"? Take a look at my code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like:

```
{if $data.complete == true}
<script type="text/javascript">toggle('true');</script>
{/if}
```